# Simple newsletter send only This is a test version of the newsletter

Tags: emails

I am using [Newsletter](https://www.drupal.org/project/newsletter) module to send newsletter to all my registered users. I have created two lists

> 1. Blog
> 2. Project (Have created templates for them as well).

My questions are;

The test mail just sends the `[node: title]` like tokens. What should I add to mail the contents of the node?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, the newsletter module isn't yet stable, so I am giving you a solution for the Simplenews module.

If you want to send Views in a newsletter, you want to use the [Viewsfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield) module. It allows you to create a Views field for your Simplenews content type. Then create a single Simplenews node and add your required View (there's a dropdown available with all active Views).

Since the content of the Views might change and you want to send the newsletter on a regular basis, you also need the [Simplenews Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews_scheduler) module. It allows you to send the newsletter for example once a week with the updated content of your selected view.

I did something like that some time ago and also added a [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2093809) on drupal.org.