# Error in simplenews when send the node more than one

Tags: emails

I am using module [simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) and when I send node more than one. Its show me this:-

> ‏This newsletter has been sent.

Why and how can I solve this and don't want to show me again.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. Why would you want to send the *same* newsletter twice?
If you want to test your newsletter, choose the option "Send test newsletter". This can be done multiple times before sending out the newsletter to all subscribers.

EDIT: I just saw your other question (you should maybe combine both) and if you want to send a newsletter containing a View on a regular basis, see my [answer to the other question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133839) or my [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2093809) on drupal.org.

Comment: no no, my problem is when send the node more than once. its show me that message

Comment: Yes, and that is by design. Simplenews only allows to send each newsletter once (to avoid spam presumably). So there's no real solution as there is no real error. Everything as expected.